# HTML file redirect

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I am not sure if you would do this in the .htacess file but,

I have a page `www.website.com/page2.html`

How would I make the URL look like `www.website.com/page2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With .htaccess under apache you can do the redirect like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

As for removing of .html from the url, simply link to the page without .html

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/page2">page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This should work for you:**

`example.com/page` will display the contents of `example.com/page.html`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

[301](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/) from `example.com/page.html` to `example.com/page`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```